# Code submission on Spoj is giving runtime error (NZEC)

Tags: java, algorithm, search

I am struggling with Runtime Error (NZEC) on Spoj for problem, 
http://www.spoj.com/problems/NHAY/

I tried so many cases from my side and everytime it is giving correct output in eclipse but could not able to find out the reason of Runtime error while submitting this on Spoj, Can anyone please help me to resolve this error.

Here is my code,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class KMP {

    public int[] lps(String needle, int needleLength)
    {
        int lps[] = new int[needleLength];

        int j=0,i=1;        
        lps[0]=0;

        while(i<needle.length())
        {
            if(needle.charAt(j) == needle.charAt(i))
            {
                lps[i] = j+1;
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                if(j != 0)
                {
                    j = lps[j-1];
                }

                lps[i] = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }

        return lps;
    }

    public List<Integer> KMPalgo(String hayStack, String needle, int needleLengh)
    {
        int lps[] = lps(needle, needleLengh);

        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        List<Integer> position = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while(i<hayStack.length())
        {       
            if(hayStack.charAt(i) == needle.charAt(j))
            {
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                if(j !=0)
                {                   
                    j = lps[j-1];
                }
                else
                    i++;
            }

            if(needle.length() == j)
            {
                position.add(i-j);
                if(j !=0)               
                    j = lps[j-1];
            }
        }

        return position;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        KMP o = new KMP();
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while(true)
        {   
            String needlLength = bf.readLine().trim();

            if(needlLength == null || needlLength.equals(""))
              break;

            int lNeedle = Integer.parseInt(needlLength);
            String needle = bf.readLine().trim();
            String haystack = bf.readLine().trim();

                List<Integer> result= o.KMPalgo(haystack, needle, lNeedle);
                System.out.println();

                for(Integer itr : result)
                    System.out.println(itr);
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the runtime error is:

```
String needlLength = bf.readLine().trim();

if(needlLength == null || needlLength.equals(""))
    break;
```

You are calling `trim()` before checking `needlLength` for `null`.

But it seems you have at least one other error. You should replace

```
if(j != 0)
{
    j = lps[j-1];
}

lps[i] = 0;
i++;
```

with

```
if(j != 0)
{
    j = lps[j-1];
} 
else 
{ 
    lps[i] = 0;
    i++;
}
```

because now you are doing at most one jump when computing a prefix function, and that is not correct.